# password protecting workbook with VBA not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a workbook that should only be accessed by a couple of people.
The below code has been placed in the workbook. 
There is a `userform` with two `textboxes`, one used for username and one used for password.

I then check those entries against entries I have created in VBA. however, It work's for one person but not the other.

RossName and Ross password allow me access to the workbook, however the GulsenName and GulsenPassword does not. It will return the `"ELSE"` function and show the MsgBox, so be false? what am I missing?
Thankyou for your help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim enteredUserName  As String
    Dim GulsenName As String
    Dim RossName As String
    Dim enteredpassword As String
    Dim gulsenPassword As String
    Dim RossPassword As String

    RossName = "RossA"
    RossPassword = "Password1"
    GulsenName = "Gulsen"
    gulsenPassword = "Password2"

    enteredUserName = Me.TextBox1.Text
    enteredpassword = Me.TextBox2.Text

    If (enteredUserName = RossName Or enteredpassword = GulsenName) And (enteredpassword = RossPassword Or enteredpassword = gulsenPassword) Then
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Unload Me
    Else        
        MsgBox ("userName or Password incorrect, please try again")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is only activated IF the user accepts to run macros. If they don't activate macros the workbook can be opened just as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **AND** to **OR**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim enteredUserName  As String
    Dim GulsenName As String
    Dim RossName As String
    Dim enteredpassword As String
    Dim gulsenPassword As String
    Dim RossPassword As String

    RossName = "RossA"
    RossPassword = "Password1"
    GulsenName = "Gulsen"
    gulsenPassword = "Password2"

    enteredUserName = Me.TextBox1.Text
    enteredpassword = Me.TextBox2.Text

    If (enteredUserName = RossName And enteredpassword = RossPassword) Or (enteredUserName = GulsenName And enteredpassword = gulsenPassword) Then
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Unload Me
    Else
        MsgBox ("userName or Password incorrect, please try again")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou, i knew something obvious i was missing, but my brain wasn't working logically.

Comment: I am trying but it saying i have to wait a couple of minutes before i can